# Access Denied (runtime error) while useing RETR in FTP COMMAND

Tags: c++, ftp, command, runtime, wininet

I'm writing a very simple `FTP manager`,when I send a message to `RETRIEVE` the `file` from server my Application fell into a `Run-time` Error and I Don't Know Why.

```
HINTERNET ftpConnection(const char* szHost,const char* szusrName,const char* szPass)
{
    HINTERNET hOpnFuncFtp=InternetOpen("FTP-Agents",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    HINTERNET hConFuncFtp=InternetConnect(hOpnFuncFtp,szHost,INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
        szusrName,szPass,INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE ,NULL);

    if(!hConFuncFtp)
    {
        SetLastError(6);
        return (HINTERNET)0xffffffff;
    }

    return hConFuncFtp;
}
```

it's how I connect and That's Right but the problem comes in other function when I'm trying to send a `RETR` command to the server:

```
FtpCommand(Connection2FTP,TRUE,INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY,"RETR /OMG/HELLO1\r\n",NULL,&respondFtp);
```

at this line my application goes to a `Run-Time` `Error`!
the `Run-Time` Error Message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7780D193 (msvcrt.dll) in FTPTrans.exe: 0xC0000005:Access     violation reading location 0x00000001.
```

btw you can find the same question in NOWHERE of `StackOverflow`.

Comment: First of all, how do you know that it's the `FtpCommand` call that causes the crash? And how do you initialize `Connection2FTP`?

Comment: In tracing code and it's exactly when I'm using 'RETR', and about Connection2FTP I just wrote it there, it comes from ftpConnection function and it works properly (I used it in other Functions -No Problem-)

Comment: And you *did* check the returned value from `ftpConnection` so it was valid?

Comment: of course my friend , and i'm using this in other functions to explore the directories and see the size of files , delete them, rename and... it works so good.

Comment: i guess the problem should be with syntax of FtpCommand, btw I saw https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt

Comment: I'm going to Retrieve HELLO1 file in /OMG/ path from server btw.

Comment: @johnsmith - Where on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384133(v=vs.85).aspx does it say that `dwContext` can be NULL?

Comment: nowhere but always we can leave it NULL if we don't have a CALLBACK operation , btw this works when I'm not using RETR command